# What is the proper way to exit the current process from a kernel module?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, process, kernel-modules

I'm writing a livepatch module to hook a function and replace it with one that causes the process to terminate. I can't call `abort()` because that calls `BUG()` and my kernel will panic on oops.

Importantly, the function must terminate the process immediately and *must not return*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm dumb. Turns out I was still using `do_exit_group()` and forgot to switch to `do_exit()`.